# Is JSON still used in applications

Tags: asp.net, json

I wanted to know if JSON is still used in live applications? I am creating a service and want to understand if I should output data using JSON too?

What is the latest standard now?

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish with this service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is very popular, and there is no sign that this is changing.

> I am creating a service and want to understand if I should output data using JSON too?

You really need to ask the potential customers of the service that question.  Or at least, give us some hint as to what the service is and what clients are likely to use it.

> What is the latest standard now?

There is no official standard for JSON.  In theory, JSON is a subset of ECMAScript (aka JavaScript), so the relevant ECMAScript standard would be normative.

In practice, JSON is implemented in many languages independently of ECMAScript.  The description on the [JSON.org](http://json.org) website, and [IETF RFC 4627](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) are probably the most relevant to someone implementing JSON for themselves, but neither of these sources have the authority of a standard.  If you want JSON libraries, the JSON.org site is a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, JSON is still very popular. Even Google web services API gives search output in JSON.

Take a look at this example:
http://zamples.com/JspExplorer/samples/google.jsp

Comment: are there any json api's you know that returns a list of items..like countries or zipcodes and so on..till date i have not been able to find any

Answer (score 0):

**Overwhelmingly yes.**  For me, JSON is the transport format of choice for AJAX requests and inter-application data sharing. To date, there are [1271](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) questions about JSON on SO.